# Oracle doubts about integration

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm starting a project and one of the requirements is an integration between databases.

I've done integration with API, WSDL, but never between databases (all oracle).

The functional design have to do is: According to the rules that I have in my application, execute a procedure in another database filling the parameters with my application data. The sp will record information in a table (in the other database) and create a ticket there.

So my question is: is it possible run through my oracle instance a procedure in another oracle instance?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You just need to [create a database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) between the databases.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink_name
  <<parameters>>
```

Then you can execute the procedure in the remote database

```
BEGIN
  schema_in_remote_db.procedure_in_remote_db@dblink_name( <<parameters>> );
END;
```

As a general architectural matter, however, I wouldn't generally have an application make a remote procedure call.  Generally, you'd want the application that you're building to be available even if the remote database is down or if the network connection between them is down.  Otherwise, your availability decreases substantially.  You also force Oracle to use a two-phase commit and distributed transactions which can be a decent amount of overhead.

Generally, you'd design the system so that you write to a local table or a queue and a separate job runs asynchronously to call the remote procedure (or a separate job in the target database polls the table you're writing to and calls the procedure locally).